# 502 Bad Gateway, Nginx 1.18 Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: php, nginx

My website is on AWS EC2. This 502 Bad Gateway came all the sudden. Nginx is deactivated.
" /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf" shows "listen = /run/php/8.1-fpm.socket"
I am a very beginner, please kindly instruct me how to restart php8.1-fpm.socket. I tried "$service /etc/init.d/php8.1-fpm start" and failed at Authentication required. In fact it asks which authentication password? php DB password, or MariaDB password? Neither works.

I checked "service --status-all | grep +" Nginx and MariaDB are all in + column.

Please help with big thanks!

Johnx